# Swift - JSONSerialization Invalid escape sequence

Tags: regex, escaping, swift5

Getting invalid escape sequence error when converting regex json string to dictionary object.

```
let exp = "{\"exp\":\"\\b(?:\\d[ -]*){4}\\b\"}"
let data =  Data(exp.utf8)
do {
    let dataObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String:Any]
    print(dataObject)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Error:

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid escape sequence around character 13." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid escape sequence around character 13.}

Answer (score 2):

I think you need

```swift
let exp = #"{"exp":"\\b(?:\\d[ -]*){4}\\b"}"#
```

Here, the raw string literal specifies the `{"exp":"\\b(?:\\d[ -]*){4}\\b"}` string, where each literal backslash is escaped with another literal backslash.

Comment: Can confirm that this works.